# Mutiple Loops in a single range statement, Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Hey I need help to create multiple loops in a single statement as:

```
for n1,n2,n3 in range(1,501):
    ........code
```

```
**TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object**
```

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you want to achieve. Do you want to get `1,2,3` in your first iteration, `4,5,6` in the second iteration, etc?

Comment: Please edit your question and elaborate what output you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

When u use `n1,n2,n3`, python expects a list/tuple to be provided instead of `range (1,501)` because only lists/tuples with dimension >= 2 can be unpacked and integers can't be unpacked.

So instead of using `for n1,n2,n3 in range(1,501):` use

```
lst = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] #Iterable with 3 values to unpack
for n1,n2,n3 in lst:
    print(n1,n2,n3)
```

Output:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

The number of values within each nested list should be equal to the number of values that u r trying to unpack. Else, an error would be thrown.

Code:

```
lst = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]] #Iterable with 4 values to unpack
for n1,n2,n3 in lst:
    print(n1,n2,n3)
```

Output:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

Code:

```
lst = [[1,2],[3,4]] #Iterable with 2 values to unpack
for n1,n2,n3 in lst:
    print(n1,n2,n3)
```

Output:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

Hope that this helps!

Comment: Imho you fail to answer the question, you don't even explain what your variable `lst` is. For your code to work, `lst` needs to be a list of iterables of size 3, i.e `lst = [(1,2,3),(4,5,6)]`.

Comment: Yeah I already explained it.  "python expects a list/tuple to be provided".

Comment: Check if my updated answer provides the needed explanation.

Comment: I have explained it in detail. I hope that this would help the OP. BTW, pls remove tht downvote.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to extract exact 3 values at one for every iteration of the loop? You can't do that directly, `range(...)` will generate an [iterator object](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Iterator), which is called once for every loop iteration and each time it will only yield one number, not three.

Assuming you want to extract 3 values for each iteration, to do this iterator friendly (and thus memory friendly on very large sets) and flexible, you could use the following example directly taken from the [itertools documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
```

This will create n shallow copies of the given iterator and call each of these copies exactly once every time a new entry is requested from `grouper`. It even has an option to fill in blanks if the given iterator doesn't exactly produce a multiple on n items.

To use it, you can do:

```
for n1, n2, n3 in grouper(range(1, 501), 3):
    print(n1, n2, n3)
```

A completely different approach could be to use three range generators and zip them together like this:

```
for n1, n2, n3 in zip(range(1, 501, 3), range(2, 501, 3), range(3, 501, 3)):
    print(n1, n2, n3)
```